# Chrome DevTools constantly losing connection over USB

Tags: android, google-chrome, windows-10, google-chrome-devtools, android-7.1-nougat

I've been doing mobile web development on this PC with this phone for 2 months now.  Every day, USB debugging with Chrome DevTools.  Today, it will NOT stay connected for more than 10 minutes.

[image]

I have restarted the PC and the phone. I switched USB ports. I have disabled USB Debugging and revoked all authorizations, then reenabled and authorized.  It keeps doing it.

Any suggestions?

Windows 10 1607
Chrome Version 59.0.3071.115
Android 7.1.2

Comment: In the spirit of eliminating variables, you've tried swapping out USB cables too, right?

Comment: Sadly nobody else on my team has a USB-C cable. I'll have to do that tomorrow.

Comment: Another variable to eliminate is Chrome versions. Download [Beta](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/beta.html) or [Canary](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html) and see if the problem persists. See [How do I choose which channel to use](https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel#TOC-How-do-I-choose-which-channel-to-use-) for an explanation of these different versions.

Comment: Canary is a good idea.  I'll give that a go.